# Как добавить запись в TextView если данные записываютс через адаптер

Tags: java, android

Читаю данные с бд

```
apapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this,R.layout.info_layout,model.ReaderWithDateBaseLite (this),new String[]{"summa","description","nameCoast"},new int[]{R.id.tvSumma,R.id.description,R.id.tvName},0);
```

Приходит естественно значение. Как сделать шаблон чтобы было к примеру так.
Пришло значние 45 гр
Выводит в TextView Сумма = 52 гр

Comment: Если вы почуяли что стандартный адаптер не покрывает ваши нужды, то лучше не полениться и написать свой адаптер в котором можете все творить что захочется

Comment: по какому принципу из числа 45 должно получится 52? что нужно сложить, сумму чисел из таблицы? и куда вывести, в каждый айтем или в отдельный виджет вне списка